# why my views didn't show in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I install laravel-5 on ubuntu 15.04
but it did not shows my views or standard views

should I do anythings more?

its my route.php file:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([

'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',

]);
```

Comment: What views not displayed? Add more details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason behind this issue is that you have not changed the permission of storage folder. Please run the following from your laravel root :

```
chmod -R 755 storage
```

if this doesn't works try

```
chmod -R 777 storage
```

Comment: Better to use `chown` or ACLs for this. `chmod 777 storage` is potentially dangerous, especially on shared hosting.

Comment: He said Ubuntu 15.04 and not shared hosting, even if you are on shared hosting changing file ownership won't help

Comment: Some shared hosts run Ubuntu 15.04, so we don't know what sort of hosting. Making the storage folder owned or writable by the `www-data` user (in Ubuntu) is a much better solution than giving every user on the server full read/write/execute access.